# I wonder why Android Fragment transactions is asynchronous? how about designed synchronous?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wonder why Android Fragment transactions is asynchronous? how about designed synchronous?

At least don't need to checkLostState every time

Comment: If you need to check "lost state" every time, your implementation is probably wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can make transactions synchronous by using `mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` or by using the new `commitNow()` method (with some restrictions, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()).